# Can CSS Include <META>?

Tags: javascript, css

When included through `<link>`, CSS files are situated inside `<head>` but do not require `<style>`. Currently I have both `<script>` and `<meta name=viewport>` located outside `<style>` but inside `<head>` as follows.

```
<head>
<meta name=viewport>
<style>HERE</style>
<link href=THERE>
<script></script>
</head>
```

Suppose I want to separate `HERE` above to `THERE` above, a CSS file. Can the CSS file also include both the `<meta>` and `<script>` parts together? Or must this be avoided as they are located outside `<style>`?

Comment: The only thing CSS files can include is valid CSS code. A CSS file cannot include HTML of any kind.

Comment: Thanks for this quick clarification. I wondered if that repeated ```<meta>``` can also be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything contained within the [`<style>` tag](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-style-element) **must** be pure CSS.

`<script>` and `<meta>` tags are both HTML tags, and **cannot** be contained *within* `<style>`, as HTML cannot be written inside of CSS.

[`<meta>`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-meta-element) is for [metadata content](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#metadata-content), and is only valid as a direct child of `<head>`. [`<script>`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-script-element) indicates JavaScript code / file references (through `<script src = "">`), and as such can be placed inside either `<head>` or `<body>`.

As such, the following is perfectly valid HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport">
  <link href="file.css">
  <script></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content</p>
</body>
```

With the following in `file.css`:

```
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Note that the CSS file only contains CSS. With the above setup, the styles written in the CSS file will be reflected on the HTML page (cascading down from the `<body>` tag), assuming the link is set up correctly.

Comment: I put ```<meta name=viewport content=width=1024px>``` to HTMs mechanically, so wondered whether this can also be isolated using the CSS, but it seems wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

No.

CSS files can include CSS.

They can't add arbitrary HTML.

If you want to include common HTML across multiple documents, use a template library (either with server-side HTML generation at run time or a static site generator at build time)

Comment: I wondered if I can also separate the ugly one-line ```<meta>``` repeated over time, but it seems impossible. Thanks for this quick answer.